# TypeScript compile import's into a single file

Tags: typescript, gulp-typescript

Inside my TypeScript application I use different import's for my own modules and node modules.

Every time i use "import" i want it to really import the module and compile it into a single js-file. Currently it looks like this:

main.ts:

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
$('body').css({'color': 'red'});
```

main.js (output)

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var $ = require("jquery");
$('body').css({ 'color': 'red' });
```

But what i want is that instead of `var $ = require("jquery");` it really imports jQuery into this file (but only if it wasn't imported earlier).

Comment: Did you mean `import "jquery"` which will import jquery to the global scope? What do you mean by "import into this file"? it's a bit ambiguous.

Comment: Copy jquery.js into main.js

Comment: I doubt if it's possible via typescript, because it's not really an import, it sounds more like a concatenation of both files. And I think it's going to make debugging harder

Comment: Im pretty sure webpack or browserify is what i need. I wonder if this isn't part of the TypeScript compiler already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> TypeScript compile import's into a single file

You need a module bundler. e.g. Webpack or browserify.

## More

Browser quickstart : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/browser.html

Comment: mentioned browserify 